# What is the meaning of MRS in foreign trade context?

Tags: meaning, initialisms

I failed to find a relevant meaning for MRS over the Internet as used in the following context:

> **Purchase Order**
>   ....
>   Delivery Terms: On X site including truck packing and in accordance with the requested specification.
>   Delivery Time: 20-24 Week from receipt of order
>   Payment Terms: 50% ADVANCE AGAINST BANK GUARANTEE + 50% After MRS

Comment: Take a look through [these](http://www.acronymfinder.com/MRS.html). It might be *marginal rate of substitution*.

Comment: Then, what does _marginal rate of substitution_ refer? I don't think it suits the context.

Comment: That was just a very quick guess I made when looking over the list I linked to. Did you see any others that seemed to fit the context in which the initialism was used?

Comment: Yes, actually there was another one (Marketing Requirements Specification) that seemed relevant, but not appearing yet to be a match.

Comment: I looked through the list again but I still didn't see anything that jumped out at me as a clear match. I also tried a few variations of Google searches but Mrs. as a married woman's title complicates the search results. Can you any further context about the document/situation this occurred in?

Comment: Yes, the most popular use is probably women's title of Mrs. that comes up as search results. Yes, I'll provide some context.

Comment: what country did this come from?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, Does it make a difference? Germany I suppose.

Comment: spose not. ....

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, I am sure it is from Germany, with confidential parts replaced with X for privacy.

Comment: @JasonStack At the moment, I guess it's either *Maritime Register of Shipping* (Russia) or *Maintenance/Repair/Services*.

Answer (score 2):

MRS is a fairly common logistics name:

[Brazil](http://www.mrs.com.br/)

and is also the [Mexican Railroad System](http://www.ciltec.com.mx/en/logistics-infrastructure/railroad/mrs-international-trade)

Page 5 of [here](http://www.omfed.com/tenders2015/TENDER%20DOCUMENTS%20GHEEVAT2014_4.2.15.pdf)

contains a similar contract to yours, it is asking the buyer for 50% up front against a bank guarantee, and 50% after delivery and installation by the logistic firm involved. In your case the logistic firm is M.R.S..